# How to use jQuery to cause ASPxButton to click?

Tags: jquery, devexpress, aspx-user-control

I have an ASPxButton:

```
<dx:aspxbutton ID="btnRefreshData" runat="server" Text="Refresh" 
                    meta:resourcekey="btnRefreshDataResource1">
                </dx:aspxbutton>
```

I have use jQuery to cause a click on the button:

```
$('#btnRefreshData').click();
```

But thing doesn't work out. The button doesn't click. Could you help me to find a solution on this?

Comment: Check by inspecting the page, if the id of the button in the html is same as that you have given. While I was working with comboboxes, then I had this same problem. When I inspected the html page, then I could see that the id was changed to `comboBox1_I`. With an `_I` added to the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, DevExpress has provided a lot of JavaScript functions to help us to do this:

```
aspxBClick("MainContent_btnRefreshData")
```

"MainContain" is the ID of Content Place Holder. The button must stay inside the content place holder to get this effected. To archive this, we call "aspxBClick" function and pass a parameter which is a string compiled of Content place holder ID and the Button's ID.

Example Code:

```
<script>
aspxBClick("MainContent_btnRefreshData")
</script>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <dx:aspxbutton ID="btnRefreshData" runat="server" Text="Refresh" 
                    meta:resourcekey="btnRefreshDataResource1">
                </dx:aspxbutton>
    </asp:Content>
```

**Additional way:**

We can call button id to do click:

```
btnRefreshData.DoClick();
```

Remember to add attribute ClientInstanceName to the button:

```
<dx:aspxbutton ID="btnRefreshData" runat="server" Text="Refresh" ClientInstanceName="btnRefreshData"
                    meta:resourcekey="btnRefreshDataResource1">
                </dx:aspxbutton>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fire click event on devexpress button on client side, define it ClientSideEvents.

You can declare a function directly in the setting of ClientSideEvents:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="ASPxButton" AutoPostBack="False">
 <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
      alert('The Click event has been invoked');
 }" />
```

or you can assign js function which will be defined in another place:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButton1" runat="server" Text="ASPxButton" AutoPostBack="False">
 <ClientSideEvents Click="ASPxButton1_click" />
```

```
function ASPxButton1_click(s, e) {
      alert('The Click event has been invoked');
 }
```

Source: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9448

Comment: You go wrong direction. My question focus on how to cause an ASPxButton to click, but not click event of itself.